# How to force all fontification to complete?

Tags: font-lock

I have a package which checks the face of a character before operating on it.

A problem with this is, the face might not yet have been calculated because of:
`jit-lock-context-time`, which delays contextual fontification.

---

How can I ensure a region of text has all it's font-faces calculated, including contextual fonts?

Comment: Why do you check the face of characters the buffer? Historically, I've done it as well, but got bitten so many times that I now avoid it at all costs. In most cases, you can use `syntax-ppss` instead.

Comment: I'd like to run a spell checker over comments, ignoring code or other symbols in the comments.

Comment: `syntax-ppss` returns a list that describes the context. Element 4 in this is non-nil when in a comment. This is a much more robust way than to check font-lock faces. (However, this does not solve the problem of ignoring other things within comments, like code.)

Answer (score 1):

`font-lock-ensure` does exactly that.  There's also `font-lock-fontify-buffer` for interactive use and older Emacsen that do not have `font-lock-ensure` yet, hence you'll often see the following construction:

```
(if (fboundp 'font-lock-ensure)
    (font-lock-ensure)
  (with-no-warnings
    (font-lock-fontify-buffer)))
```

Note that it may be necessary to call `font-lock-flush` before `font-lock-ensure` to tell font-lock that a certain font-lock region is outdated.

Comment: Maybe, it is worth noting that if one switches on some minor mode that adds/changes/removes some font-lock keywords one should run `font-lock-flush` before `font-lock-ensure`.

Comment: @Tobias this should be made part of the answer - since font-lock-ensure on it's own wasn't working. The issue with flushing is it causes re-fontification, I'd like just to do remaining fontification, instead of adding extra work.

Comment: `font-lock-ensure` does the remaining fontification and `font-lock-flush` is the big hammer when that doesn't work. I've edited the answer appropriately.